# Como alinhar um elemento em cima de outro com css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá.

Tenho esse código html:

```
<p class="titulo">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">(ABC)</a> Texto de Teste
</p>
```

Ele normal fica assim: **(ABC) Texto de Teste**

Como faço deixar o **(ABC)** em cima do **Texto de Teste** e centralizado?

Assim:

```
    (ABC)
Texto de Teste
```

Obs: Utilizo o twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode centralizar o texto dentro do parágrafo e colocar a propriedade `display:block` no elemento `a`, exemplo:

```css
p.titulo{
  text-align:center;
}
p.titulo a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p class="titulo">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">(ABC)</a> Texto de Teste
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer com que um elemento ocupe uma linha inteira sozinho modificando o estilo (via atributo ou CSS). Basta indicar `display: block`. Esse é o padrão para *div*'s, mas para links por exemplo o comportamento é de `display: inline`, logo o `display: block` deve ser suficiente no seu caso.

O elemento vai ocupar toda uma linha... Você pode ainda ajustar o comprimento com `width` e o alinhamento com `text-align`, `padding`, `margin` etc.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário adicionar uma div também.

```
<p class="titulo">
  <div id="umaDivQualquer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">(ABC)</br> Texto de Teste
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#umaDivQualquer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Abraço jovem.